# Create a function about summarize+group by

Tags: r, function, dplyr

I am trying to create a function for the "summarize+group" by code.
Here is the data set I am working on. Columns including id, country, Apple, Orange, Jackfruit, Banana (with ==1 if the person likes this fruit, and ==0 if the person does not like it)

Here is the function code I am using:

```
summarize_pct<-function(x,y){
  sample %>%
    group_by(x, y) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(perc = n()) %>%
    mutate(Apple = c("dislike", "like")[y + 1])  %>%
    tidyr::spread(y, perc, fill = 0) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(dislike, like), ~./sum(.))
return(summary)
}
summarize_pct(Country,Apple)
```

But I got the error message....

Here is the data I am working on:

```
structure(list(id = 1:30, Country = c("USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", 
"USA", "USA", "USA", "USA", "Germany", "Germany", "Germany", 
"Germany", "Germany", "Germany", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", 
"UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "UK", "France", "France", "France", "France", 
"France", "France"), Apple = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), Banana = c(1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L), Orange = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L), Jackfruit = c(0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 
0L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 
1L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 0L, 0L, 1L)), row.names = c(NA, -30L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use this as a function you might need to use non-standard evaluation. Using curly-curly operator from rlang 0.4.0

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

summarize_pct<-function(df, x , y) {
    df %>%
     group_by({{x}}, {{y}}) %>%
     dplyr::summarise(perc = n()) %>%
     mutate(temp_name = c("dislike", "like")[{{y}} + 1])  %>%
     select(-{{y}}) %>%
     tidyr::spread(temp_name, perc, fill = 0) %>%
     ungroup() %>%
     mutate_at(vars(dislike, like), ~./sum(.))
}

summarize_pct(sample, Country,Apple)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Country dislike  like
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 France    0     0.353
#2 Germany   0.308 0.118
#3 UK        0.462 0.235
#4 USA       0.231 0.294

summarize_pct(sample, Country,Orange)
# A tibble: 4 x 3
#  Country dislike  like
#  <chr>     <dbl> <dbl>
#1 France    0.2   0.2  
#2 Germany   0.133 0.267
#3 UK        0.267 0.4  
#4 USA       0.4   0.133
```

Comment: Hi, Ronak, it worked when I copy + paste these codes.

Comment: However, when I try to change Apple to Orange, it does not work...          summarize_pct<-function(df, x,y){
  df %>%
    group_by({{x}}, {{y}}) %>%
    dplyr::summarise(perc = n()) %>%
    mutate({{y}} = c("dislike", "like")[{{y}} + 1])  %>%
    tidyr::spread({{y}}, perc, fill = 0) %>%
    ungroup() %>%
    mutate_at(vars(dislike, like), ~./sum(.))
}

summarize_pct(sample, Country,Apple)

Comment: @iceylovedata ohh..It needed a small change. I have updated the answer. Can you check now?

Comment: It worked! That's very brilliant. Could you explain "mutate(temp_name = c("dislike", "like")[Apple + 1]) "? I do not understand fully how you add a column and assign dislike if Apple=0, and like if Apple=1....

Comment: @iceylovedata it is shorthand for `ifelse(Apple == 0, "dislike", "like")` but in a faster way. It uses indexing technique to select values based on index. For example, see `c("like", "dislike")[c(1, 2, 1)]`